# function within catch block throws exception

Tags: c++, exception

if I have a try catch block in my code, and the functions within the catch block generates an exception, what happens to that exception?

Answer (score 2):

there's nothing special about throwing from a `catch` clause.

generally, if the `catch` clause is only used for some local cleanup then it's a good idea and good general programming practice to rethrow the current exception from the `catch` clause, and that's what the `throw` without argument is for.

throwing from a destructor, on the other hand, is generally problematic, because a destructor might be invoked automatically during stack unwinding (this then terminates the program).

Comment: And to complete: `throw;` outside of a catch-block will kill your process.

Comment: so say I have a function foo, which might throw an exception, is it ok to call foo from within a catch block?